# Awk not printing what is wanted

Tags: awk

my attempt:

```
awk '$4 != "AZ" && max<$6 || NR==1{ max=$6; data=$0 } END{ print data }' USA.txt
```

I am trying to print the row that
does NOT have "AZ" in the 4th column
and the greatest value in the 6th column

the file has 6 colums
firstname lastname town/city state-abv. zipcode score

```
Shellstrop Eleanor Phoenix AZ 85023 -2920765
Shellstrop Donna Tarantula_Springs NV 89047 -5920765
Mendoza Jason Jacksonville FL 32205 -4123794
Mendoza Douglas Jacksonville FL 32209 -3193274 
Peleaz Steven Jacksonville FL 32203 -3123794
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your attempts, please do add your samples of input and expected output also in your question, so that we can test our solutions too, cheers.

Comment: If the same minimum number appeared 3 times in the 6th column would you want the first such line printed or the last or all 3 or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your attempts, please try following `awk` code. This checks if 4th field is NOT AZ then it compares previous value of `max` with current value of $6 if its greater than previous value then it assigns current $6 to max else keeps it to previous value. In `END` block of `awk` program its printing its value.

```
awk -v max="" '$4!="AZ"{max=(max>$6?max:$6)} END{print max}' Input_file
```

To print complete row for a maximum value found would be:

```
awk -v max="" '$4!="AZ"{max=(max>$6?max:$6);arr[$6]=$0} END{print arr[max]}' Input_file
```

Comment: it works but it seems to be over complicated

Comment: @guyconfusedwithawk, Trust me it isn't overcomplicated at all :)

Comment: I do agree it cannot be simpler than this.

Comment: @guyconfusedwithawk search for *ternary operator*, it is not limited to AWK language, JavaScript use very same syntax, python has `value1 if cond else value2`, you might start at wikipedia [?:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please explain why we must be explicit about setting `max` variable

Comment: @Daweo  that's so it's specifically a string, not a strnumn, and so is less than any number **in some locales**, otherwise it'd be compared as 0 instead of `""` in it's first comparison and stay at that value through the whole script execution since all numbers are negative and so the output would be a null string. I would not recommend doing it this way for portability and it depends on specific data "types". In all min/max calculations you should start by setting the min/max to the first value read, e.g. `awk '$4!="AZ"{max=( (!c++) || $6>max ? $6 : max )} END{print max}' file`.

Comment: or `awk '$4!="AZ"{max=( max=="" || $6>max ? $6 : max )} END{print max}' file` would be fine too because while that also relies on max being `""` for the first comparison it;s doing a literal string comparison of `max` to `""`, not comparing `""` to an input data value like `$6` and hoping that the relative order of chars vs numbers in the current locale produces the desired result.

Comment: The difference between the values of `max` with and without an initial `max=""` are that without initializing it `max`s value is `zero-or-null` while afterwards it's just `null` and so you get different results from each when comparing `max` to a number.